# need to get value from the database and populate a drop down list using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I need to populate a dropdown list when I select a certain value
and the options need to be queried from the database.

Can I achieve this from jQuery ?
If I can then please I would appreciate any help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery and AJAX

```
jQuery.post('dropdownValues.php', {parameterSentToServer1:'value', param2:'value2'}, function(data){jQuery('#mydropdown option').remove(); //Remove current options
for (var option in data.results){
    jQuery('#mydropdown').append('<option value="'+option.value+'">'+option.name+'</option>');
}}, 'json');
```

in dropdownValues.php you'll need to build a json object with the result of the sql query, the object must be in this format(for working well with the above script):

```
echo '{results:[{value:1, name:'Option1'}, {value:2, name:'Option2'}]};
```

Answer (score 0):

Does "drop down list" refer to a popup menu (e.g. a `<select>` element)? If so, you can populate it as follows:

```
var data = ["Hello World!", 42, true, "Foo"];
var select = document.getElementById("myPopupMenu");

for (var i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++)
{
    var option = new Option();
    option.innerHTML = data[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

However, this is in plain JavaScript—I'm not sure what the jQuery syntax would be.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely achieve this.  You need to use AJAX.

Ajax is a subject all in itself, but basically what you will do is call a javascript function when a selection is made from the dropdown.  The javascript function will request a page from your server via Ajax, and the server will return a small chunk of data, which you can then use (from Javascript again) to re-populate the second drop down (or whatever).

Google around for how to do Ajax with Jquery.  Here's a page that might get you started:  <s>http://www.ajaxlines.com/ajax/stuff/article/use_jquery_ajax_to_create_options_in_a_dropdown_menu.php</s>

Comment: the link is dead, but another potential alternative would be: http://fixlog.blogspot.com/2008/12/use-jquery-ajax-to-create-options-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Note that appending each `<option>` to the `<select>` will reload the DOM for each append. This can become very slow if you have a lot of options.
It is more efficient to build the whole `<select>` with its option in a string and then replace the existing one.